# Selecting all text that is not a phrase in Russian

Tags: regex

I have a JSON file which contains data that looks something like this:

> {"id":"599874c2cc6ffaf42d4c3751","idMemberCreator":"5966727c2d9c33e207a0f5b2","data":{"listAfter":{"shortLink":"LubhJK4r","idShort":71,"name":"Что
>   за бред*!",
>   "id":"59972f276d4e2ed2ad13eab6","idList":"59957b7d842a7cc1c3dfa039"}...

This contains a certain number of phrases in Cyrillic characters, surrounded by quote marks, such as `"Что за бред*!"`. These phrases may also contain numbers, spaces, and punctuation such as `*,.!?`

I would like to create a regular expression that selects everything *except* these phrases, so that I can delete all the meta data and keep just the Russian phrases. A phrase will start with a quote mark followed by either a number (e.g. 2017) or an uppercase Cyrillic character, and will continue until the next quote mark.

I know how to select the phrases themselves:

`[А-Я0-9][а-яА-Я0-9 *,.!?]+`

However, selecting everything but these phrases is complicated by the fact that the rest of the file contains numbers and commas.

Can you help me to create the regular expression that I need?

Comment: So basically you want to select **only** the Russian phrases, no?

Comment: which language/flavour?

Comment: do you expect only one such a phrase in a line, does it always go with the **name** tag?

Comment: BTW, the russian phrase is incorrect. It should look like `Что за бред!` :-)

Answer (score 1):

If that is an JSON, you can traverse over it and filter out with your regex.

```js
var json = {
  "id": "599874c2cc6ffaf42d4c3751",
  "idMemberCreator": "5966727c2d9c33e207a0f5b2",
  "data": {
    "listAfter": {
      "shortLink": "LubhJK4r",
      "idShort": 71,
      "name": "Что на бред*!",
      "id": "59972f276d4e2ed2ad13eab6",
      "idList": "59957b7d842a7cc1c3dfa039"
    }
  }
};

function deepJsonFilter(json, pattern) {
  return Object.keys(json).reduce((acc, key) => {
    if (typeof json[key] === 'object') {
      acc[key] = deepJsonFilter(json[key], pattern);
    } else if (!pattern.test(json[key])) {
      acc[key] = json[key];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
}

console.log(deepJsonFilter(json, /[А-Яа-яёЁ]+/));
```

Comment: A Russian letter can be matched with `[А-Яа-яёЁ]`.